# Unit test cases are not executed in Visual Studio with NUnit and Spring

Tags: c#, nunit, spring.net

I am not able to execute test cases in Visual Studio. I have reinstalled Visual Studio and [ReSharper](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ReSharper), but still it is not working. Please give some suggestion to execute test cases in Visual Studio.

- Visual Studio version: 2017
- Dependency injection using the [Spring Framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spring_Framework)
- Test case framework - NUnit

Comment: What do you mean by not able to execute? Test are invisible or you get some kind of error?

Comment: @Johnny Execution time of Test case is approx 2 to 3hrs. If I run only one test case then it also takes 30min to run

Comment: Re *"not able to execute test cases"*: What happens? Do you get an error message? If yes, what is it? If no, please explain. Thanks in advance.